# Changing specified values on numpy array in a certain dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Wondering if there is an easy way to do this:

Say I have an numpy array with the shape `(2,3,2)`, for example:

```
x = 
[[[ 0, 1],
  [ 2, 3],
  [ 4, 5]],

 [[ 6, 7],
  [ 8, 9],
  [10,11]]]
```

If I wanted to replace all the entries that corresponded to `axis=1` and `position=0`, with zero, I could do this easily:

```
x[:,0,:] = 0
x = 
[[[ 0  0]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]]

 [[ 0  0]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]]
```

However, what If I had a list of axes that I wanted to perform these operations on. Is there a built-in numpy function for this? Ideally it'd look something like this:

`array_replace(array=x,axis=1,pos=0,replace_val=0)`

Which would give the same array as above.

I can think of a way to do this by flattening matrices and calculating where the positions of each variable would be based on the dimension of each array, but I'm wondering if there is already something built into numpy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but this isn't the best way to do it, I can guarantee it. Numpy is powerful enough that such operations can be vectorised easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a tuple of slices and then use the specific axis for the position. So you can define such function as:

```
def array_replace(array, axis, pos, replace_val):
    array[(slice(None),) * axis + (pos,)] = replace_val
```

So what we do is constructing a 1-tuple with a `slice` object `(slice(None),)`. A slice object is what Python generates behind the curtains for a colon `:`. So `x[:,0,:]` is a simple representation for `x[(slice(None),0,slice(None))]`.

Next we repeat this slice `axis` times (the number of times before the specified axis), followed by the position we want. The remaining slices are optional, so we do not specify these here. We then use numpy's broadcasting to assign the `replace_val` to all these indices.

This then generates:

```
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
>>> array_replace(array=x, axis=1, pos=0, replace_val=0)
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a reference for what the `slice` function is doing "behind the curtains"? I haven't come across this usage before but it seems very useful.

Comment: @lstbl: `slice` is constructor. It construct a `slice` object. It does not do much, it is simply there as a representation of `:`. Suc that an object with a `__getitem__` function, can handle slices. It has a `start`, `step` and `stop` attribute.